# Converting RAW Blackmagic Intensity Card frames

Tags: video, ffmpeg, conversion, libav, yuv

I am trying to convert raw video frames that I have captured using a Blackmagic Design Intensity card. The output frames are of the format:

```
YCbCr 4:2:2 packed 8 Bit UYVY Abekas
```

How can I convert this to a more usable format? My goals are to extract frames as images and sets of frames as videos.

I have tried using FFmpeg to convert the files but I cannot find the correct format. The example I am using is a file containing the raw data of a single frame. FFmpeg converts the file but it is distorted so I know that means my pixel format is incorrect. I am starting to think FFmpeg does not support the pixel format I need.

```
ffmpeg -s 720x486 -i snapshot.yuv snapshot.jpg
```

The output comes out almost correct but is mostly green.

Here is the output from FFmpeg. The rawvideo format is detects is incorrect. It should be Y422 instead of I420.

```
ffmpeg version N-64009-g389d453 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun 16 2014 15:43:30 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: 
  libavutil      52. 89.100 / 52. 89.100
  libavcodec     55. 67.100 / 55. 67.100
  libavformat    55. 43.100 / 55. 43.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.101 / 55. 13.101
  libavfilter     4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
[rawvideo @ 0x2af1c20] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, rawvideo, from 'snapshot.yuv':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 139968 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 720x486, 104976 kb/s, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[swscaler @ 0x2ae13e0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, image2, to 'snapshot.jpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.43.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 720x486, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc55.67.100 mjpeg
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> mjpeg (mjpeg))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x2ae13e0] Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speedloss
[rawvideo @ 0x2af2ec0] Invalid buffer size, packet size 174960 < expected frame_size 524880
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=7.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=N/A    
video:140kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Comment: If ffmpeg doesn't have support for it, you could [submit a bug report](http://ffmpeg.org/bugreports.html) with a sample picture and the current ffmpeg output. Maybe some developer can add parsing functionality.

Comment: You can force ffmpeg to read a specific format by saying `ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt <format> -s <size> -i input.yuv ...`, where the pixel format is one of those listed in `ffmpeg -pix_fmts`